# How to make only 1 refresh on multiple clicks python/django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a site using GCP python API, which is quite slow at making pull requests. So I have cached the area of the template using this data, and in the view I check if the cache is still active before making any more requests (not a copy n pasted code so if theres any typos ignore em :) )

```py
def gcpProjectsView(request):
    gcpprojects = None
    cached_time = None
    if cache.get(make_template_fragment_key('gcp')) is None:
          cached_time=timezone.now()
          gcpprojects = get_gcp_projects()
    return render (request , 'gcp/gcpprojects.html', {'gcpprojects':gcpprojects,'last_update':cache_time})
```

To manually update the data, I have a refresh button that points to this view:

```py
def refresh_gcp(request):
   cache.delete(make_template_fragment_key('gcp'))
   return redirect('gcpProjectsView')
```

The problem is that if the user clicks the refresh button 5 times the view makes 5 GCP Api calls, it needs to only do 1. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Is the refresh button inside a form or is it just a link?

Comment: just a link, but it can be a form if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use a simple form with a button. Buttons can be disabled   using simple javascript when clicked.

Because you're redirecting back to the same template in the view the button should be re-enabled again once it has 'refreshed'.

In this example snippet replace the action with whatever url routes to `refresh_gcp`.

```html
<form method="GET" action="<url that points to refresh_gcp>">
  <button type="submit" onclick="this.disabled = true;">Refresh</button>
</form>
```

This was the simplest solution I could think of that didn't involve implementing some sort of token validation for requests.

Comment: Thanks thats a way more simple solution than I was thinking perfect

Answer (score 1):

**Use django session :**

```
def refresh_gcp(request):
   clicked = request.session.get("click")
   if clicked:
       return render(request,"your_html",{"disable":True})  
       # Set Button disable or not in your html by using context...
   else:
       request.session["click"]="user_click"
       cache.delete(make_template_fragment_key('gcp'))
       return render(request,"your_html",{"disable":False})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll try it. I'm confused by the if name: line though, where does name come from?

Comment: @Colonbracket sorry it's my bad...I edit my answer.